# Best way to go about creating in-house analytics for my Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, analytics

I have a Rails 3 app that I'm looking to create in-house analytics for. The items I need to track are impressions (and unique impressions), clicks that come from those impressions, and conversions that come from those clicks. And these are all user-specific so each user can see how many impressions, clicks, and conversions they've received.

What is the best way to go about this? Should I create a separate rails app and call it with pixels? Or should I include all the analytics code in the same app?

Also, are there any analytics platforms already out there that I can customize to meet my needs?

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: Have you taken a look at Google Analytics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you start re-inventing the wheel, Google Analytics provide a developer API (via OAuth, among other choices) that may provide you with the ability to do what you need (provide each user with a view of their own data).

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html

Building your own, while it may seem like an initially basic thing to do, could have serious performance implications further down the line, and Google provide a very detailed view of the the data.

*If* you really want to write your own, I would strongly urge you not to hit the database for each request you want to track.  Keep the data in Redis, or one of the alternatives and periodically persist it to the database via a background task.

Comment: Wow I didn't know about the GA developer api. I can track all the specific events I need and pull reports via the api. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Only problem with the GA api is that it's easier to do a credit card TRX then get authenticated with GA, especially if you don't want to bind your own account to the app.

Answer (score 4):

If, however, you don't want to put your data into the clutches of our Google Overlord :) then you might indeed consider rolling your own. I have twice before - and I'm doing it again right now: better this time, of course!

If your traffic is not *very* high and you're running on any decent server platform then adding a tracking system is not going to tax your Rails app noticeably (I know that depends on what 'decent server platform' means but this stuff is pretty cheap these days). Writing to a database is typically very fast - you'd have to have shedloads of clicks to not want to do this straightaway. You can probably bypass most if not all of your before_filters and so on to get a lightning response. One app that runs 2.3.9 uses Metal to do this, for example.

In my new tracking system I have an STI table that goes with models derived from an Activity model; in here you can record both impressions and clicks. Impressions are recorded as the page is built and clicks are recorded using AJAX.

I'm not going to bother with fancy graphs and so on - I'm happy with raw numbers - but these could be added, of course.

At the moment my system is just in the usual app/ folder but I'll probably move it to an engine so I can re-use it more easily.

Hope that helps!

BTW I use Google Analytics as well for a range of sites and it's OK - I just like to do this bit myself.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are going to associate Google Analytics data with a specific user then you might need to double-check the privacy implications. Google doesn't allow their data to be associated with any identifying information about the users being tracked.

If there is a problem then you could try out Piwik as it's open source and you can do what you like with it. It's written in PHP, not Ruby so that might be an issue. As @d11wtq mentions, tracking systems can have performance issues if not built in the right way so you'd be better off starting from something that's already proven to work if possible.